# error with my loop: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python

```
def highest_value():
    """so here normally it should return the highest value """
    h = get_live_data_from_api('MY1', 'NO')
    hv = h['RawAQData']['Data']
    highest_number = None
    max_key = -1
    for k in hv:
        if highest_number is None or highest_number < hv[k]:  
            highest_number = hv[k]  
            max_key = key
    return(max_key)
print(highest_value())
```

I would like to know how can I change my code to make it work please

I tried to create an item but did not work I'm a bit lost

Comment: It looks like `hv` is a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is missing some information, so it is not clear what the problem is. However, based on the comments in the code, it appears that the highest_value function is intended to find the key in the hv dictionary that has the highest value.

One potential issue with the current implementation is that you are using the key variable to store the key of the dictionary entry with the highest value, but key is not defined anywhere in the code. Instead, you could use the k variable, which is already being used to iterate over the keys in the hv dictionary.

Here is how you could update the highest_value function to fix this issue:

```py
def highest_value():
    """so here normally it should return the highest value """
    h = get_live_data_from_api('MY1', 'NO')
    hv = h['RawAQData']['Data']
    highest_number = None
    max_key = None
    for k in hv:
        if highest_number is None or highest_number < hv[k]:  
            highest_number = hv[k]  
            max_key = k
    return(max_key)
print(highest_value())
```

This updated version of the function uses the k variable to store the key of the dictionary entry with the highest value. It also initializes the highest_number and max_key variables with None instead of -1, which makes it clear that these values are not yet set.
im glad i helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have the same error which is "list indices must be integers or slices, not dict" if you know how to solve it I would be glad